# Nodejs getting error while download files using FTP

Tags: node.js, nodes, nodejs-stream, node-ftp

I am using node-ftp package for FTP connection. Below code example

```
const FTPClient = require('ftp');
const fs = require("fs");
let ftp_client = new FTPClient();
let ftpConfig = {
    host: '94.208.170.184',
    port: 21,
    user: '99*******',
    password: '******'
}

var downloadList = [];
//create a connection to ftp server
ftp_client.connect(ftpConfig);
//list directory and files from server.
ftp_client.on('ready', function() { 
    ftp_client.list('xmlfiles',function(err, list) {
        if (err) throw err;
        list.map(function(entry){
            console.log(entry.name);
            if (entry.name !== '.' || entry.name !== '..') {
                downloadList.push(entry.name);
             }
        });
    downloadList.map(function(file, index){
      console.log(file);
      // Download remote files and save it to the local file system:
      ftp_client.get('xmlfiles/' + file, function(err, stream) {

        if (err) throw err;
        stream.once('close', function() { ftp_client.end(); });
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));

      });
    });
    ftp_client.end();
    });
  });
```

I am getting error like:
[image]

Is their is any way we can download files using batch process

Comment: Hi @jbrtrnd can you please me on my this problem

Comment: what is reponse from console.log(file); in above code ? @Sudhir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code and I am able to achieve download functionality.

Below are code sample.

```
const FTPClient = require('ftp');
const fs = require("fs");
let ftpConfig = {
    host: '94.208.170.184',
    port: 21,
    user: '99*******',
    password: '******'
}
let downloadPathDir = path.join(__dirname, '../assets/download-xml/');
var downloadList = [];
const ftpConnection = async (callback) => {
    try{
        let ftp_client = new FTPClient();
        ftp_client.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(`Error in ftp connection: ${e}`);
        });
        ftp_client.on('ready', function() {
            ftp_client.list('/xmlfiles',function(err, list) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(`Error in gracenote file listing: ${err}`);
                }
                if (!err){
                    list.map(function(entry){
                        if (entry.name !== '.' && entry.name !== '..' && typeof entry.name !== 'undefined') {
                            downloadList.push(entry.name);
                        }
                    });
                    callback(downloadList);
                }
            });
        });
        ftp_client.end();
        ftp_client.connect(ftpConfig);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const fileDwonload = (allFileNames,fileCount) => {
    let currentXmlFile = allFileNames[fileCount];
    let fileDtl = {"orgFile":currentXmlFile,"upFile":removeWhiteSpace(currentXmlFile)};
    let xmlfile  = downloadXMLFile(fileDtl);
    xmlfile.then(function (data) {
        let tempFileCount = allFileNames.length;
        let newFileCount = fileCount + 1;
        if(newFileCount < tempFileCount){
            fileDwonload(allFileNames,newFileCount);
        }
    });
}

let downloadFile = {
    callDownload : async function() {
        ftpConnection(function(allFileNames) {
            fileDwonload(allFileNames,0);
        });
    }
}

const downloadXMLFile = async function (fileDtl) {
    try{
        let fileName = fileDtl['orgFile'];
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!fs.existsSync(downloadPathDir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(downloadPathDir);
        }
        let xmlfilepath = downloadPathDir + fileName;
        let upfilepath = fileDtl['upFile'];
        if (!fs.existsSync(xmlfilepath)) {
            let d = new FTPClient();
            d.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log(`Connection Error While Downloading: ${e}`);
            });
            d.on('ready', function() {
                if (fileName !== '.' && fileName !== '..' && typeof fileName !== 'undefined') {
                    d.get(`xmlfiles/${fileName}`, function(err, stream) {
                        if (err){
                            console.log(`XML download Failed: ${err}`);
                        }
                        if(!err){
                            stream.once('close', function() {
                                d.end();
                            });
                            stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(downloadPathDir+ upfilepath ,{flags: 'w'}));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            d.end();
            d.connect(ftpConfig);
        }
    });
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(`XML download Failed Connection: ${err}`);
    }
};
```

If anyone has better solution. Feel free to update here.